# How to get month name from number in Mule 4

Tags: date, mule, dataweave, mule4

How to get Month in String (For eg. "March") when input is Month in number (for eg. "3") using Dataweave 2.0/Mule 4.

Input : "3"
Output : "March"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy date using the month string as the month number, then format the date to month name with format "MMMM".

For Mule 4.4+ this can be done cleanly with the `date()` function of the [Dates module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-dates) that helps as to create a `Date` from parameters:

```js
%dw 2.4
output application/json

fun getMonthName(month: String)=dw::core::Dates::date({year: 2023, month: month as Number, day: 1}) as String {format:"MMMM"}
---
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"] map getMonthName($)
```

Output:

```json
[
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
]
```

If you are using an earlier Mule 4.x then we need to resort to some horrible string manipulation for dates:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun getMonthName(month: String)=do {
    var fakeMonth="2023"
    var fakeDay="01"
    ---
    (fakeMonth++ month as Number as String{format:"00"} ++ fakeDay) as Date {format:"yyyyMMdd"} as String {format:"MMMM"}
}
---
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"] map getMonthName($)
```

Comment: This Month value will be dynamic. 
Let's say I have to use payload.month. In this case, it won't work.

Comment: ```date({year: 2023, month: payload.month as Number, day: 1}) as String {format:"MMMM"}``` @VatsalMehta .. wont this work?

Comment: I gave you just an example of the method. You can replace the fixed value of the month for whatever you want. For easier reuse and clarity I updated the answer with a function that encapsulates the method and provide examples for every month.

Comment: Thanks for that solution, but that's  only works in Mule 4.4.0 version. And we are using Mule 4.3. So would appreciate if any solution that works with 4.3 version.

Comment: You should provide that information as part of the question. I'll provide an alternative for Mule 4.3.

Comment: For 4.3, we can try something like this.
("9999-" ++ (payload.date) ++ "-01") as Date as String {format:"MMMM"}

Comment: Updated for Mule <4.4.